# Does an initially analytic wavefunction remain analytic under time evolution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-equations, analyticity

My question has to do with when "mathematically nice" properties of a wavefunction (e.g. analyticity) are preserved under time evolution.

Consider the Schrodinger equation $i\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle=H|\psi(t)\rangle$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $R^N$ (for example, an $N$ dimensional particle in a box). Suppose the initial wavefunction $\langle x|\psi(0)\rangle$ is an analytic function and suppose that it's fourier series converges pointwise.

Are there conditions on the Hamiltonian $H$ that will guarantee that $\langle x|\psi(t)\rangle$ remains analytic for $t>0$, and that guarantee that its fourier series will converge pointwise for all $t>0$?

Comment: A time-independent hamiltonian will keep an initially analytic solution analytic in the future. For a general hamiltonian, if the eigenspace of the hamiltonian is analytic, solutions will remain analytic for all times, but this is only a sufficient condition.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to provide a sketch of a proof, or a reference?

Comment: Note that the time evolution operator $e^{-iHt} = \sum_n e^{-iE_nt} |n \rangle \langle n|$ for time-independent H. If you express your initial wavefunction as a linear combination of some of these basis functions $|n\rangle$, then the time evolution operator will simply evolve them with a phase $e^{-iE_nt}$. Essentially, you are relying on the fact that you start with some set of analytic $|n\rangle$ which remain analytic because they are time-independent.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But infinite series of analytic functions can converge to non-analytic functions, so even if all eigenfunctions are analytic, the wavefunction may not be analytic (e.g. fourier series for a step function). How do we know that an initially analytic wavefunction can't evolve into a non-analytic wavefunction?

Comment: Because your initial wavefunction is analytic, and time evolution will not add any new eigenfunctions to the expansion, just a phase factor that does not depend on $x$. The case you mentioned is applicable when your initial wavefunction is one such non-analytic infinite series.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean *analytic* in the complex-analysis sense, that a Taylor series exists for it, or equivalently that it's complex differentiable.  This really feels like it belongs on math.se and not physics.se.